# How does the Controller typically pass HTML and Javascript into the ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in my ASP.NET MVC controller class named `Index`. It calls a stored procedure that queries the `Person` table and uses the results to generate a string, which corresponds to the body of an html document with a table, paging links, and some javascript splashed in there. The controller takes the string from the stored procedure and passes it to the view.

However, I have a problem in my view. In Webforms, I simply put a `<p>` tag on my form and set its `innerHTML` property to the string returned and then shut off `ViewState`. I tried something similar in my ASP.NET MVC view, except it displays my HTML and Javascript as text. The controller returns a collection of result objects with one item, whose `Content` property is equal to the HTML table, paging links and Javascript generated in the stored procedure.

Here is what I have in my view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content);
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to inject the HTML and Javascript inside a cell of a table, except it displays the cell's contents as text instead of treating it as HTML. Most of the methods I tried have actually given me errors.  This method at least gives me text in my document.

Comment: Please show the code and explain what is the question?

Comment: Seems like a really bad idea to generate the HTML inside the stored procedure. In ASP.NET MVC, you typically query the database and get back a **list of objects** and then you pass that list to the view, and **let the view** do the formatting / layout of those results (it's called "separation of concerns")